# R: Remove duplicated rows in a dataframe which contains in a second column a value

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame()` in `R` which contains 3 columns:

```
id<-c(12312, 12312, 12312, 48373, 345632, 223452)

id2<-c(1928277, 17665363, 8282922, 82827722, 1231233,12312333)

description<-c(Positive, Negative, Indetermined, Positive, Negative, Positive)
```

I want to delete the duplicated rows by `id` which in `description` have the value of `Indetermined`.

Comment: what would be your output? from the example above, is id = 12312 has to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a probem for `filter()` so:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(count = 1) %>% # count all ids
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count = sum(count),Duplicate = count>1) %>% # count how often each id occurs and mark duplicates
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!Duplicate & description == "Indetermined") # filter out duplicates that are "indetermined"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best approach, but this should do the trick.

```
(d <- tibble(id,id2,description))
d[!d$id %in% (d$id[d$description == "Indetermined"]),]
```